# Is a.out executable format still supported by current Linux?

Tags: linux, executable, elf

I have read at many places that Linux has now switched to using ELF. However, none of them specify if [a.out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A.out) format executables can still run in Linux or not.

Comment: Yes. As long the kernel has support compiled in.

Comment: Ok, in that case is this support enabled in a standard Ubuntu 32-bit distribution? How do I check that? I don't have an a.out executable handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. On ubuntu 12.04, here is how I verified it -

```
view /boot/config-$(uname -r)
```

On line 739-740 (out of 7247) there are these lines,

```
CONFIG_HAVE_AOUT=y
CONFIG_BINFMT_AOUT=m
```

So, this machine can run `a.out` files.

**Edit**

12.04 is supported until April 2017, but I checked on Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit and a.out is still supported (until at least April 2019) on 32-bit Ubuntu,

Line 789 of /boot/config-3.13.0-24-generic

```
CONFIG_HAVE_AOUT=y
CONFIG_BINFMT_AOUT=m
```

Comment: Cool. This seems a.out is enabled in 32-bit, but not in 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: -1, on current versions of Ubuntu/Debian it is deactivated.

Comment: @Kay It's still supported on Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit, I just checked.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, strange, I must have messed up the grep then. -1 removed.